# Avoid XAML Dependency Property to read while Collapsed

Tags: wpf, xaml

On a ViewModel a property of "OperationStepInstance" is commanding a huge process if asking for its value. 
My question is, if there is a way to not ask for its value while in XAML the element is hidden or collapsed.

By default, even if it is collapsed, a Dependency property is always asked for its value.

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding Path=StatusInstance.IsProductive, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProductionOrderInstance.Key}" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}"  />
                            <TextBlock Text="-" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,4,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProductionOrderInstance.OperationStepInstance.Number}" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="/" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,0,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StatusInstance.Key}" Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" Margin="4,0,4,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="" Grid.Column="5" Style="{StaticResource ItemTextStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        </Grid>
```

Comment: Property getters should just return current values. They should not start "huge processes".

Comment: Yes, its correct. Even of that it helps to explain best why I am asking for a methode to not read hidden values in XAML.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233676/wpf-stop-binding-if-a-ui-element-is-not-visible

Comment: @Andy I searched but did not find that thread. Seems to match, yes.